# Do ketdione molecules have diol tautomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, tautomer

In my chemistry textbook there's a keto-enol tautomerism example:

[image]

But will it also be in equilibrium with pent-1,3-dien-2,4-diol in a reaction like this or will it just be a functional isomer?

[image]

Comment: No, such tautomer doesn't exist in practice, or at least is too unstable to be anything more then intermediate

Comment: @Mithoron So it's just a functional isomer and can't exist at equilibrium?